# Dynamic text boxes

Tags: c#, textbox

I'm accessing record from my database .. and generating dynamic text boxes to number of records fetch..

Then I'm assigning text to these text boxes from the dataset ..

I'm doing this all on the `Change` event of combo box .. But when I change the event .. that is change value in combo box the value still remain the same in text boxes i.e fetch from previous event ...

The values in text boxes do not update.

Here is my code

```
private void ComBoSem_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    semID();
    conct.MyConnection();

    try
    {
        SqlCommand SubjectsCMD = new SqlCommand("select SubjectName from Subjects where Sem_ID= '" + semesterID + "'", Connectioncs.con);
        SqlDataAdapter SubjectDA = new SqlDataAdapter();
        conct.openCon();
        SubjectDA.SelectCommand = SubjectsCMD;

        SubjectsCMD.ExecuteNonQuery();

        subjectDS.Clear();

        SubjectDA.Fill(subjectDS, "sub");

        if (subjectDS.Tables["sub"].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            TextBox[] txtsubject = new TextBox[subjectDS.Tables["sub"].Rows.Count];

            DateTimePicker[] DtPker = new DateTimePicker[subjectDS.Tables["sub"].Rows.Count];

            Label lblSubjectName = new Label();
            lblSubjectName.Text = "Subjects Name";
            lblSubjectName.Location = new Point(60, 115);
            GB_DateSHeet.Controls.Add(lblSubjectName);

            Label lblPaperTime = new Label();
            lblPaperTime.Text = "Subjects Name";
            lblPaperTime.Location = new Point(300, 115);
            GB_DateSHeet.Controls.Add(lblPaperTime);

            ////// label Control Finished here 

            for (int i = 0; i < subjectDS.Tables["sub"].Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                //// dynamic Textboxes 
                txtsubject[i] = new TextBox();
                Point p = new Point(50, 143 + (i * 28));
                txtsubject[i].Size = new Size(168, 21);
                txtsubject[i].Location = p;

                DtPker[i] = new DateTimePicker();
                DtPker[i].Location = new Point(300, 143 + (i * 28));

                txtsubject[i].Text = subjectDS.Tables["sub"].Rows[i]["SubjectName"].ToString();
            }

            conct.openCon(); 

            // adding controls to GridView 
            for (int i = 0; i < subjectDS.Tables["sub"].Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                GB_DateSHeet.Controls.Add(txtsubject[i]);

                GB_DateSHeet.Controls.Add(DtPker[i]);
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No Record  Found");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need `c` tag.

Comment: Yup. please remove the `C` tag

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title